# Lifecycle functions involved in StackNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Currently, I read some state from `AsyncStorage` in `componentWillMount`. However, some screens modify what is in `AsyncStorage`, and it does not appear that `componentWillMount` is called when returning (`this.props.navigation.goBack()`) to a screen, so they don't receive the update.

What, if anything, is called? What are the component lifecyle functions that are called on the *return* to a screen? Are any of these only called once, when the screen is to be shown again?

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidFocus` is currently in design not avaiable yet, see [react-native open issue #51](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/51).

Try this alternative way [react-navigation-addons](https://github.com/satya164/react-navigation-addons).